Flex and Bison: Compilation Error on Xubuntu
I'm using Xubuntu and trying to work with Flex and Bison to create a simple parser. Here's the process I'm following:

Created a .lex file and a .y file.

Ran the following commands to generate the C files and compile them:
flex test.l
bison -d test.y
gcc lex.yy.c test.tab.c -o test -L/usr/lib -lfl -ly

However, I'm encountering the following errors during compilation:
test.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
test.tab.c:963:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  963 |       yychar = yylex ();
      |                ^~~~~
test.tab.c:1104:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1104 |       yyerror (YY_("syntax error"));
      |       ^~~~~~~
      |       yyerrok
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Steps I've Tried:

Verified that Flex and Bison are installed.

Checked GCC installation and libraries.


My Environment:

Flex version: flex 2.6.4

Bison version: bison (GNU Bison) 3.8.2

GCC version: gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0


Does anyone know what might be causing these issues? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!



Most of this is in the documentation, for example from  https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting-Function.html : The Bison parser expects to report the error by calling an error reporting function named yyerror, which you must supply.

Looks like Ubuntu has liby.a in a libbison-dev package. (That library just includes a default yyerror function and a main; see https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Yacc-Library.html

@Shawn.a files contain object modules and cannot help with missing declarations since the latter requires source code.

can you please tell me stepp by step how to solve this issue

@EricPostpischil Yes, you still have to declare it like the documentation I linked to describes. You just don't have to write the function if you'd rather use the liby version.

(you also have to provide a declaration for the yylex() function defined in the flex-genetated lexer (and usually you'd run bison -d first so the lexer can include the appropriate generated header; see https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_mono/flex.html#SEC16 and https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Lexical.html ))

I think there is a way to make gcc recognise the library from Bison.   (i am not sure if what i am saying is accurate but i saw some one do it in windows(he poorly explaind what he is doing or i didn't anderstand[he coppied the libs from flex and bison and putted them in codebloks libs]) i couldn't do the same since we have a differentset up )

Lots of issues here, but they're mostly around not understanding how bison/flex (or yacc/lex) work together. Bison is a parser generator that, given a grammar, creates C code that sees if input matches that grammar. It gets input by calling the function yylex() repeatedly to get a sequence of tokens. Sometimes that function is written by hand, sometimes it's generated by a lexer generator like flex. In the latter case, the generated lexer needs to know what to return from its implementation of yylex(). The -d option to bison/yacc generates a header file, yy.tab.h, that contains definitions of the tokens that the function should return. This header needs to be included in a code block near the beginning of the lexer definition. The flex manual includes an example:
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

This means that you need to run bison/yacc first, before flex/lex (You're doing it in the opposite order):
bison -d test.y
flex test.l

The C source file created by bison expects two functions to be defined: The already mentioned yylex(), and yyerror(), which is used for error handling. You have to include a declaration for yylex() manually; the one for lexers created by flex is:
int yylex(void);

which should go in a code block at the start of the bison input file.
The other function, yyerror(), should either be written by you, or you can just fall back to the default one found in liby. If using that, it needs to be declared in the bison input file at the same place you declare yylex(), as
int yyerror (char const *);

If you write your own, it should have the same argument type, though return value doesn't really matter - it isn't used by the code that calls the function (bison has a toggle to turn on an extended version that takes additional arguments, but let's stick with the basic version for now). If you write your own yyerror(), you don't need to link with liby -- all it has is definitions for yyerror() and main() (You presumably have your own definition of that one). If you do want to use the default yyerror(), Ubuntu family Linux distributions include the library in a package named libbison-dev that you have to install; it's not part of the base bison package for some reason.
